# まあいいか or まあいっか or まあええか or まあえっか

Tags: slang

I noticed some people write the following,

> まあいいか or まあいっか or まあええか or まあえっか

Which is the correct one? What is the etymology of this expression, and for what situation? Please give me some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which is the correct one?

All four forms are "correct".

Roughly speaking, 「ええ」 is the Western Japan version of 「いい」.  Thus, 「いっか」 is the more casual/informal version of 「いいか」, and 「えっか」 is that of 「ええか」.

Roughly speaking again, 「いいか」 and 「いっか」 are heard more often in Eastern Japan (including Tokyo) and 「ええか」 and 「えっか」 are heard more often in Western Japan.

In my hometown Nagoya, which is located right in the middle of the country, all four forms are actually used pretty much with equal frequency.  This, however, would be a Central-Japan-only phenomenon.

Moving on to the meaning and nuance..

「まあ」(also pronounced just 「ま」 colloquially) in this expression is an adverb meaning "***just barely satisfactorily***".  In other words, it is used to describe an "***Oh well***" kind of quality.

「いいか」 is casually asking yourself if something is good enough for you as in "***Should I take it?  Well, I guess I should (because I don't have a better option)***."

Thus, it is not such a simple task to "translate" 「まあいいか」 as it only uses three words. Options would include:

***"Oh well, I/we will take it, then."***

***"Alright, I guess I'll just call it good (for now)."***

As always, the context itself will select a good translation for you.

Answer (score 2):

All the words you posted are correct.

"まあいいか" and "まあいっか" --> are used the common sentences. 
"まあええか" and "まあえっか" ---> are often used in Kansai region.

"まあいいか" "まあいっか" "まあええか" "まあえっか" all Japanese can the meaning.
you can use all of them in every area in Japan.